# Rename RelatedField ordering filter in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In a django rest framework APIView we specify ordering fields using the same method as the [search filters](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) and therefore we can specify ordering using related names.

```
ordering_fields = ('username', 'email', 'profile__profession')
```

The route would look like this: `https://example.com/route?ordering=profile__profession`

However we would rather avoid to display the relation between the models in the api and then specify `profession` instead of `profile__profession`. Such as `https://example.com/route?ordering=profession`

Can this be achieved without having to implement the sorting in the  `APIView`'s `def get_queryset(self):`?

Comment: I believe that you can do it using django_filters as a filter backend in DRF - if this is an option for you: http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filters.html#orderingfilter

Comment: agree with @opalczynski, it's better done with [OrderingFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#orderingfilter)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be achieved with a minor change in `def get_queryset(self)`.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query = super(UserListView, self).get_queryset().annotate(profession=F('profile__profession'))
    return query
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to write your own `OrderingFilter` based on the Django REST framework one by overriding `get_ordering` and using a dictionary to map the "short name" to the full queryset string.

Comment: what if I want reverse "short name" ordering, this means I need to include `-short_name` mapping `-full_queryset_path` into the dictionary?

Comment: Then you remove the `-` before your dictionary lookup and prepend it to the alias afterwards